# How I have write code query in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoDB(Using Mongoose middleware) in which I have collection of following format.

```
{ _id : ObjectId("1"), tag: 'A038', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("2"), tag: 'A038', flag: 'R', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("3"), tag: 'A039', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("4"), tag: 'A040', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("5"), tag: 'A040', flag: 'R', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("6"), tag: 'A041', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("7"), tag: 'A042', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
```

On that collection,
How I have write code query in mongoDB? 
to get records like this.

```
{ _id : ObjectId("3"), tag: 'A039', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("6"), tag: 'A041', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
{ _id : ObjectId("7"), tag: 'A042', flag: 'P', size: 60, name: 'productA' }
```

Is it possible in mongodb?

Thank You

WJ

Comment: what query did you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection.find({_id:{"$in":[ObjectId("3"),ObjectId("6"),ObjectId("7")]}},function(err,results){
console.log(results);
})
```